# Multiple Google sheet Querying by date

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have multiple sheets. I want to get the data from these sheets by a date query.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the Result  sheet as below
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:B; Sheet2!A3:B}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''")
```

Comment: Another issue is that some sheets column numbers are not same